# Catch Exception and respond with custom message without skipping OutputFormatter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am developing WebAPI and want to catch all my ApiException custom exceptions and display WebAPI-friendly responses. The ApiException exception can be thrown from `Action` or `Filter` like `IAuthorizationFilter` or `ActionFilterAttribute`.

First I tried to use `IExceptionFilter` but later I found that the `IExceptionFilter` handles only exceptions thrown from Actions and not from other Filters.

```
public class ApiExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
    
        var exception = context.Exception;
    
        if (exception is not ApiException responseException)
        {
            responseException = new ApiException(ResponseMessageType.UnhandledException);
        }
    
        context.Result = new ObjectResult(new ResultMessageDto(responseException))
        {
            StatusCode = responseException.HttpStatusCode
        };
    }
    
}
```

The second approach that I found many suggest to use is the Middleware but this is not the correct way by WebAPI design.

```
    public class ErrorHandlerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    
        public ErrorHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
    
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                var response = context.Response;
                response.ContentType = "application/json";
    
                if (exception is not ApiException responseException)
                {
                    responseException = new ApiException(ResponseMessageType.UnhandledException);
                }
    
                response.StatusCode = responseException.HttpStatusCode;
                await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new ResultMessageDto(responseException), new JsonSerializerOptions()
                {
                    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
                    PropertyNamingPolicy = null
                });
            }
    }
}
```

The Middleware exception handling skips WebAPI MVC `OutputFormaters` and responds only in JSON or what is set by the developer. This solution is bad by design because do not respect `Accept` header.

How to handle `Exceptions` in `Actions` and `Filters` without `leaving MVC scope`?

Comment: Have you tried to play with [order of filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#override-the-default-order)?  Can you please add full repro showing the problem (i.e. filters which are not handled)? Also you can handle the accept header in the `ErrorHandlerMiddleware`.

Comment: Have you tried changing the execution order of your filters? Is there a short circuit?

Answer (score -1):

I feel it is best to handle in Middleware, Here is a sample code. I am using Json but over here, you can use any output formatter (even custom ones).

```
 public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
 {
    try
    {
        await next(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
    }
}

private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
{
   int statusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
   string exceptionType, exceptionDetail;
   context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

   switch (exception)
   {
    case ArgumentNullException:
          exceptionType = "Argument Null Exception";
          exceptionDetail = exception.Message;
          break;
      case ApiException:
          exceptionType = "API Exception";
          exceptionDetail = exception.Message;
          break;
   default:
          exceptionType = "Unhandled"
          exceptionDetail = "Something went wrong";
          break;
   }

    var problemDetails = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails
    {
        Status = statusCode,
        Type = exceptionType,
        Title = "An error has occurred within the PromComm Application",
         Detail = exceptionDetail,
         Instance = context.Request.Path
     };

    // You can use any formatter here even with custom messages
     var problemDetailsJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(problemDetails);

     context.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
     await context.Response.WriteAsync(problemDetailsJson);
}
```

Comment: I have explained why it is bad to use Middleware in my case and you post an example which I have posted in my question. You skip OutputFormatters and respond in JSON ignoring Accept header.

Comment: @Tomas, you can always add context.Response.Headers.Add(...)